# Double search values in the same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search "developer" and "publisher" about a record. They are both in the same table. 
Can I search with a unique query or I have to search two times?

I wish something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM developers
WHERE id_dev = 1 AS developer
AND id_dev = 2 AS publisher
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case statement to output either  `developer` or `publisher` depending on the `id_dev` column:

```
SELECT *, case when id_dev = 1
               then 'developer'
               when id_dev = 2
               then 'publisher'
          end 
FROM developers 
WHERE id_dev in (1,2)
```

if `id_dev` can only be either `1` or `2` then you can remove the `where` clause completely.

Comment: It will be nice to add some explanation